# Laravel working with relations that arent related

Tags: laravel, relation

Consider I have three models: `Subscription`, `Description` and `Expense`.

Each Subscription belongsTo a Description, and each Description hasMany Expenses:

Model Subscription:

```
public function description()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Description::class);
}
```

Model Description:

```
public function expenses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Expense::class);
}
```

Model Expense:

```
public function description()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Description::class);
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve all expenses made for a subscription, based on the Description. When I have a single subscription, I can do that as follows:

```
$subscription->load(['description.expenses' => function ($q) use (&$transactions, $subscription) {
    $transactions = $q->with('description')
        ->get());
}]);
```

But when I want to check all expenses that have been done for all subscriptions, I am unsure how to go about it. I've tried using `hasManyThrough`, but I think that wouldn't work at all, since either my `Description` nor my `Expense` have a `subscription_id`. I also do not want to set up a direct relation for `Subscription` and `Expense`.

Any pointers how to fetch all expenses that have been made for all subscriptions? Or rather, the sum of all expenses for all subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually could do just the same thing as I already posted:

```
Subscription::all()->load(['description.expenses' => function ($q) use (&$transactions) {
    $transactions = $q->get();
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could append an attribute on the `Subscription` model:

```
<?php
class Subscription extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['total_expenses'];

    ...

    public function totalExpenses()
    {
        return $this->description()
                    ->with(['expenses'])
                    ->get()
                    ->pluck('expenses.amount', 'amount')
                    ->sum('amount');
    }
}


// do something...
Subscription::all()->each->total_expenses
```

Comment: Thanks, I never really used the `$appends` stuff, but I will look into it. The above didn't work for me however, but I can at least go and learn about `$appends` :)